# Find out if a user has channels

Tags: youtube-api

how we can via API 2.0 find out if the user has channels and if they have channels find the first channel to push the video to. we are a little stumped on this.. any help would be awsome

Answer (score 0):

From v3, I know a good way to figure it out is, to do a channels->list call and to receive a channelNotLinked error.

From analogy, I'd suspect do a basic request involving user's channel and get an error.